# Can't get in line edited row in Xpages Dojo Data Grid to Save

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have created an enhanced Dojo Data Grid in an Xpages App. No I want to add an editable column. I get conflicting info on whether you can do this with viewJsonService or if you must use a viewItemFileService. I can't get either way to work. Would prefer to use Json, as everything that I need to do in this code works in Json, but I cannot even get any data to appear with the FileService. I understand to get the Json to work you need to have a site document set up and allow a "GET."

My code for the viewJsonService is below:

```
<xp:panel style="width:885.0px;height:300px">

                <xe:restService pathInfo="gridData" id="restService1"
                    jsId="restServiceID">

                    <xe:this.service>
                        <xe:viewJsonService viewName="(dbAllRspPCTasks)"
                            var="rstEntry" systemColumns="4">
                            <xe:this.columns>
                                <xe:restViewColumn name="ID">
                                    <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return rstEntry.getColumnValue("ID")}]]></xe:this.value>
                                </xe:restViewColumn>
                                <xe:restViewColumn name="status">
                                    <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return rstEntry.getColumnValue("status")}]]></xe:this.value>
                                </xe:restViewColumn>
                                <xe:restViewColumn name="category">
                                    <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return rstEntry.getColumnValue("category")}]]></xe:this.value>
                                </xe:restViewColumn>
                                <xe:restViewColumn name="title">
                                    <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return rstEntry.getColumnValue("title")}]]></xe:this.value>
                                </xe:restViewColumn>
                                <xe:restViewColumn name="notes">
                                    <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return rstEntry.getColumnValue("notes")}]]></xe:this.value>
                                </xe:restViewColumn>
                            </xe:this.columns>
                            <xe:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:return viewScope.get("ID");
                }]]></xe:this.keys>
                        </xe:viewJsonService>

                    </xe:this.service>

                </xe:restService>

                <xp:button value="Save" id="button4" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="norefresh">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[restServiceID.save();]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>


                <xe:djxDataGrid id="djxDataGrid1"
                    storeComponentId="restService1" initialWidth="100%"
                    rowSelector="25px" rowsPerPage="100"
                    dojoType="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" autoHeight="10">

                    <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn1"
                        field="category" label="Category">
                    </xe:djxDataGridColumn>

                    <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                        <xp:dojoAttribute name="autoWidth"
                            value="true">
                        </xp:dojoAttribute>
                        <xp:dojoAttribute name="canSort"
                            value="false">
                        </xp:dojoAttribute>
                    </xe:this.dojoAttributes>

                    <xe:this.errorMessage><![CDATA["Sorry...error loading tasks"]]></xe:this.errorMessage>

                    <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn2"
                        field="status" formatter="displayIcon" width="25px" label="Sts">
                    </xe:djxDataGridColumn>

                    <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn3"
                        label="Task" field="title" width="300px">
                    </xe:djxDataGridColumn>

                    <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn4"
                        label="Notes..." field="notes" width="auto" editable="true">
                    </xe:djxDataGridColumn>

                    <xp:eventHandler event="onFocus" submit="false">
                        <xe:this.script><![CDATA[dijit.byId('#{id:djxDataGrid1}').canSort = function(col){
  return false;
};]]></xe:this.script>
                    </xp:eventHandler>

                </xe:djxDataGrid>

                </xp:panel>
```

Per, OK on a test server I created a Web Site Document and checked PUT in the allowed methods and rebooted the server.

When I check

http:///api/data

I get a

{
    "code":403,
    "text":"Forbidden"
}

and I do not know why. What are some things that I should look for to ensure that I can enable a put?

Bryan

Comment: Bryan, you need to allow HTTP PUT (and not GET - which is always allowed).

Comment: Per, OK on a test server I created a Web Site Document and checked PUT in the allowed methods and rebooted the server.

When I check

http:///api/data

I get a

{ "code":403, "text":"Forbidden" }

and I do not know why. What are some things that I should look for to ensure that I can enable a put?

Bryan

Comment: Make sure that you have enabled Domino Access Services: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Enabling_IBM_Domino_Access_Services_on_a_server_das901&content=apicontent

Comment: Per, I did that, restarted server, still doesn't work.